# Best way to read the ttyUSB0 output

Tags: linux, bash

My problem is if I use *while* command I receive output but I get stuck into *while*. If I use this example below I arrive late to get output from tty.
So what is best way to read the output and exit from script?

```
#!/bin/bash

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -icanon min 1 time 1
echo -e '\xff\x09\x00' > /dev/ttyUSB0
cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0

exit
```

Comment: Baudrate can be wrong specified, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120992/why-does-cat-ttyusb0-not-produce-output.

Comment: The Baudrate of my device is 9600 and works fine. The problem is I get stuck in cat command and the script does not exit.

Comment: What's the point of that separate `cat`? Can't you just have `tee >(cat -v)` together with `echo` in a pipeline?

Comment: you can show me an example?

Comment: As I said: `echo -e '\xff\x09\x00' | tee >(cat -v) >/dev/ttyUSB0`. (Also, please mention me with @).